# Python Regular Expression to Edit First Comment

Tags: python, regex

I am writing a python script to edit only the first comment block in my files.
I have a comment block that looks like this:

```
############################
##
## Comment to 
## be changed
##
############################

############################
## Don't want to change
############################
```

I am trying to write a regular expression to only find the first comment block and replace it so it looks like this:

```
############################
##
## Comment has 
## been changed
##
############################

############################
## Don't want to change
############################
```

As of right now I have:

```
editedCommentFile = re.sub(r'\#{2,150}.*?\#{2,150}.*?\s*', replString, searchedString, 1, re.DOTALL)
```

Unfortunately this only matches the first row of '#' and the 3 characters of the next line '## '. It looks like this:

```
############################
##
## Comment has 
## been changed
##
############################ Comment to
## be changed
##
############################

############################
## Don't want to change
############################
```

I am thinking that somehow I need the regex to stop pattern matching once it reaches the blank newline between the first comment block and the next.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: if your question was correctly answered/solved, please accept the answer, so other SO users with the same/similar problem (like me) know that the provided answer/solution worked for you.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\#{3,150}` to require 3-or-more `#` characters:

```
import re

searchedString = '''\
############################
##
## Comment to 
## be changed
##
############################

############################
## Don't want to change
############################'''


replString = '''\
############################
##
## Comment has 
## been changed
##
############################'''

editedCommentFile = re.sub(r'\#{2,150}.*?\#{3,150}', replString, 
                           searchedString, 1, re.DOTALL)

print(editedCommentFile)
```

yields

```
############################
##
## Comment has 
## been changed
##
############################

############################
## Don't want to change
############################
```

---

When you use `\#{2,150}` then `r'\#{2,150}.*?\#{2,150}'` prematurely matches

```
############################
##
```

which is why you would get

```
############################
##
## Comment has 
## been changed
##
############################
## Comment to 
## be changed
##
############################
```

instead.